# Making my python for loop run in parallel

Tags: python, bash, parallel-processing

I have a python for loop that executes a bash script as below (I've simplified it to include just what needs to be shown), I need it to run all of these bash scripts at the same time that are in the for loop, but waiting until they are all complete before continuing in series. The bash script is the ONLY part I want running in parallel. It is doing things downstream within the same for loop that needs to be done in series. Is this possible?

The following below works in series. No parallel execution of the script because of .wait(). If I remove .wait(), it errors almost immediately, with anything downstream no longer functioning as expected.

```
for i in range(0, len(10)):

    path = 'folder_'+'%02d'%i
    os.mkdir(path)
    os.chdir(path)

    command = 'bash dosomething'
    subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True).wait()

    THINGS IN SERIES

    os.chdir('../')
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the wait after you've started all of the subprocesses. Instead of changing the current working directory in the parent, set it for the child.

```
processes = []
for i in range(0, len(10)):
    path = 'folder_'+'%02d'%i
    os.mkdir(path)
    command = ('bash dosomething')
    processes.append(subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True,
        cwd=path))

# you can do other things here

for p in processes:
    p.wait()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import Parallel, delayed
import multiprocessing

counts = range(10) 
def sub_command(i):
    path = 'folder_'+'%02d'%i
    os.mkdir(path)
    os.chdir(path)

    command = 'bash dosomething'    
    subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True).wait()
    os.chdir("../")

cpu_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()

Parallel(n_jobs=cpu_cores)(delayed(sub_command)(i) for i in counts )
```

Comment: subprocess.Popen is to create the process and mange. we are implementing multiple process. so I used parallel .

Comment: joblib has extra overhead that isn't needed for this task. `Popen` already runs in the background, no need to double the number of processes involved.

Comment: The goal is to run an external bash command. joblib created a process so that you can chdir but it still needs to run the bash script. The script would be another process so an extra level of processes was created.

Comment: It may have some overhead, but it didn't crash unlike other options I've tried. For what I needed, this solution was absolutely perfect. Thanks!